# Efficient way of calculating quadratic forms: avoid for loops?

Tags: r, quadratic

I want to calculate N (N is big) [quadratic forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms).  I am using the command 'quad.form' from the R  package 'emulator'. How can I implement this without using a for loop?

So far, I am using

```
library(emulator)

A = matrix(1,ncol=5,nrow=5) # A matrix

x = matrix(1:25,ncol=5,nrow=5) # The vectors of interest in the QF

# for loop
QF = vector()
for(i in 1:5){
QF[i] = quad.form(A,x[,i])
}
```

Is there a more direct and efficient way to calculate these quadratic forms?

Something intriguing is that

```
quad.form(A,x)
```

is (10 times) faster than the for loop, but I only need the diagonal of this outcome. So, it would still be an inefficient way of calculating the N quadratic forms of interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
colSums(x * (A %*% x))
```

?  Gets the right answer for this example at least ... and should be much faster!

```
library("rbenchmark")
A <- matrix(1, ncol=500, nrow=500)
x <- matrix(1:25, ncol=500, nrow=500)

library("emulator")
aa <- function(A,x) apply(x, 2, function (y) quad.form(A,y))
cs <- function(A,x) colSums(x * (A %*% x))
dq <- function(A,x) diag(quad.form(A,x))
all.equal(cs(A,x),dq(A,x))  ## TRUE
all.equal(cs(A,x),aa(A,x))  ## TRUE
benchmark(aa(A,x),
          cs(A,x),
          dq(A,x))
##       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
## 1 aa(A, x)          100  13.121    1.346    13.085    0.024
## 2 cs(A, x)          100   9.746    1.000     9.521    0.224
## 3 dq(A, x)          100  26.369    2.706    25.773    0.592
```

Comment: it's not THAT much faster than `apply`... ;)

Comment: agreed. surprised me a little bit.

Comment: this is presumably fast enough now, but if it's too slow you could (1) try an `Rcpp` solution or (2) try to parallelize the problem into chunks ...

Comment: Thank you. The first command works well in my example (A is 5x5 and x is 5x2000) and it is much faster, indeed. There are some (negligible) numerical differences, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `apply` function:

```
apply(x, 2, function (y) quad.form(A,y))
```

If you make the matrices larger (500x500) it becomes clear that using `apply` is roughly twice as fast than using `quad.form(A,x)`:

```
A <- matrix(1, ncol=500, nrow=500)
x <- matrix(1:25, ncol=500, nrow=500)

system.time(apply(x, 2, function (y) quad.form(A,y)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.183   0.000   0.183 

system.time(quad.form(A,x))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.314   0.000   0.314
```

#### EDIT

And @Ben Bolker's answer is about 1/3 faster than `apply`:

```
system.time(colSums(x * (A %*% x)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.123   0.000   0.123
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. This is an interesting alternative to Bolker's answer. The efficiency of your method, in my real scenario, is in between Ben Bolker's method and the method I described at the end of my question.